# The integration formula of $\int \sin^n{x}\cos^{m}{x}\ dx$.

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I am in war with my textbook. It says that
$\int \sin^n{x}\cos^m{x}\ dx=\frac{\sin^{n+1}x\cos^{m-1}x}{n+m}+\frac{m-1}{n+m}\int \sin{x}\cos^{m-2}\ dx$.

Then I wrote the proof. Here is what I got.
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\int \sin^n{x}\cos^m{x}\ dx&=\int \sin^n{x}\cos^{m-1}{x}\cos{x}\ dx\\
&=\int \sin^{n}{x}\cos^{m-1}\ d(\sin{x})\\
&=\cos^{m-1}x\frac{\sin^{n+1}{x}}{n+1}-\int \frac{\sin^{n+1}{x}}{n+1}(m-1)\cos^{m-2}{x}\ dx\\
&=\frac{\sin^{n+1}{x}\cos^{m-1}{x}}{n+1}-\frac{m-1}{n+1}\int\sin^{n+1}{x}\cos^{m-2}{x}\ dx
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

Maybe you know what I missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your miss is here:$$\int \sin ^nx\cos ^{m-1}xd(\sin x)=\cos ^{m-1}x\frac{\sin ^{n+1}x}{n+1}-\int \frac{\sin ^{n+1}x}{n+1}(m-1)\cos ^{m-2}xd({\bf cos x})$$ and similarly as you have done, can use $$\int \sin ^nx\cos ^mxdx=\frac{1}{m+n}\int \sin ^{n-(m+n)+1}x\cos ^{m-1}xd(\sin ^{m+n}x)=\frac{\sin ^{n+1}x\cos ^{m-1}x}{m+n}-\frac{1}{m+n}\int \sin ^{m+n}x \left((1-m)\sin ^{-m}x\cos ^mx-(m-1)\sin ^{2-m}x\cos ^{m-2}x\right)dx=\frac{\sin ^{n+1}x\cos ^{m-1}x}{m+n}+\frac{m-1}{m+n}\int \sin ^nx\cos ^{m-2}(\sin^2x+\cos^2x)xdx$$ so I think there should be a $\sin ^n$ in the second term of the r.h.s

Comment: oh, yah, i couldn't see that. Thanks a lot, Alexis...